How to Query Generic Skills by Store Role ID in AWS AppSync GraphQL?
I'm working on a project where I need to map our generic skills to store-specific skills. This is a custom requirement, and I'm using AWS AppSync with GraphQL. Below is my schema:
Store Table
type Store {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  location: String
}

Skill Table (Our Existing Generic Skills)
type Skill {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  alias: String
}

StoreSkill Table (Store-specific Skills)
type StoreSkill {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  storeId: ID!
}

StoreRole Table
type StoreRole {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  storeId: ID!
}

StoreSkillRole Table (Mapping Store Skills to Store Roles)
type StoreSkillRole {
  id: ID!
  storeSkillId: ID!
  storeRoleId: ID!
  storeId: ID!
}

SkillToStoreSkills Table (Mapping Generic Skills to Store Skills)
type SkillToStoreSkills {
  id: ID!
  storeSkillId: ID!
  skillId: ID!
}

Requirement:
I need to query our generic skills and store skills by storeRoleId in a single query. The expected result should list all generic skills associated with a specific storeRoleId.

What I've Tried:
I've tried creating relationships between these tables in my GraphQL schema, but I'm not sure how to construct a query that retrieves the generic skills by storeRoleId.
The graphql schema is provided by senior staff and I have to play around this schema
Question:
How can I write a query in AWS AppSync or GraphQL to list our generic skills  and store skills by storeRoleId?

Schema Relationships:

StoreSkill is linked to StoreRole via StoreSkillRole.
SkillToStoreSkills maps our generic Skill to StoreSkill.

Any help on how to achieve this in a single query would be greatly appreciated!
